# Schengen visa for an Indian student in Ireland

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, ireland, iceland

I currently studying in Ireland and would like to apply for a Schengen visa to visit Iceland. I'm planning to go by the end of January.

1. Where to apply for visa in Dublin?
2. What are the general requirements for a student and the financial requirements?
3. How to make sure that you are not rejected?
4. How to get the maximum time for visa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Royal Danish Embassy](http://www.utl.is/index.php/en/where-you-can-apply-for-a-visa).
2. [Application - basic requirements](http://www.utl.is/index.php/en/application-basic-requirement).
3. Make sure you provide all that is required of you and hope for the best.
4. Make your case for requiring 90 days.